# Python Class Method Not Used?

Tags: python, class, methods, apache-beam

Looking at this block of code below, I don't see the expand method ever called downstream.

```
class ReadWordsFromText(beam.PTransform):
    
    def __init__(self, file_pattern):
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
    
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll.pipeline
                | beam.io.ReadFromText(self._file_pattern)
                | beam.FlatMap(lambda line: re.findall(r'[\w\']+', line.strip(), re.UNICODE)))
    
p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner())

words = p | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText('gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')

counts = (words 
          | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())

lower_counts = (words
                | "lower" >> beam.Map(lambda word: word.lower())
                | "lower_count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement())
```

Does it automatically get triggered when the words instance is created? (I'm trying to understand Python in general in the context of Apache Beam in this case)

```
words = p | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText('gs://apache-beam-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt')
```

Comment: Which part of this code exactly did you expect to call the `expand` method? How do you know that it's not called?

Answer (score 0):

This class inherits from the  `beam.PTransform` class, which is not shown.

In order for it to support custom operators in the flavor they are used is in the mess bellow, it have to do *a lot* of things. The only methods called by the language itself are enclosed in a `__` prefix and suffix, such as methods used to implement the behavior with operators such as `|` (`__or__`) and `>>` (`__rshift__`)  (see the complete magic method listing in the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) document). That superclass have to implement these, and any of them might be calling  the `expand` method.

Answer (score 0):

A transform's expand() method should be called as soon as one writes `input | transform`. I am surprised you're not seeing it get called when writing `words = p | 'read' >> ReadWordsFromText(...)` (it does for me; try printing something out in that method).

Note, however, that actually executing the pipeline (e.g. doing the Read and the subsequent FlatMap) on the resulting data) *is* deferred. You need to do `p.run()` or, if you're trying to use things interactively, `interactive_beam.collect()` to trigger execution.